# Why is wire:click not triggering function in livewire v3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I've just upgraded my application from livewire2 to livewire3 and now none of my button clicks are working:

**/resources/views/livewire/myexample.blade.php**

```
<div>
 <button wire:click="doStuff()">
                        Go
                    </button>
</div>
```

**/app/livewire/myExample.php**

```
namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Houses extends Component
{
    public $isOpen = 0;
    
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.myexample');
    }

    public function doStuff()
   {
        dd('this never fires');
   }

}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: Which version of Livewire v3 are you on? Use `composer show -D` to check. Secondly, what does your layout look like, and where is it located?

Comment: Are there any errors in your console? And do you have Alpine.js installed manually from before, via npm or a script tag?

Comment: I'm running v3.0.0-beta.4. My layout is in resources/views/components/layout. No errors in the console. Yes I installed Apline.js manually via npm.

Comment: Alright, so Alpine.js is now included with Livewire, so you should not install it separately. Also, I would suggest you try to update to beta5 by doing `composer update livewire/livewire`

Comment: Ok. Doesn't seem to have made any difference unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm, ok. If you check your console, `window.Livewire` undefined? Alternatively, if you inspect your html, can you find the Livewire init script? In v3 it should be injected automatically. Can you try to clear you cache? `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: Yeah you're right- window.Livewire is undefined (although window.livewireScriptConfig exists) and I can't find the Livewire init script. Clearing the cache didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Have you properly followed the [upgrade guide](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/upgrading) such as the change to `@livewireScripts`?

Comment: @Yinci I did update livewireScripts to livewireScriptConfig. Looks like I didn't add Livewire.start() to the app bundle though. I've done that now and window.Livewire is now defined. Thank you so much!